# How to display an overlapping window using PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to display a window when I press a button. When I click the button the parent window  remains there and new window is displayed for a fraction of a second and disappears.
How can I display the new window over the previous window that contains the button.

Comment: What have you tried? If you post some code it will be easier for people to help you. Maybe create a [QTimer](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtimer.html) and connect its `.timeout` to your window's `.close`?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're not keeping a reference to the child window, and so it's getting garbage-collected immediately after it's shown.

Your button handler probably looks something like this:

```
def handleOpenWindow(self):
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.show()
```

Instead, you need to do this:

```
    self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.window.show()
```

Or this:

```
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
    window.show()
```